# Convergence absolutely in causal time series

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, arima, inequality

I am studying a theorem given in a Time Series Book (Brockwell and Davis, Time Series Theory and Methods, pag 83, proposition 3.1.1) 
The proposition is the next one:

[image]

I have the following question:

At the end, is concluded that since $E[\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi_j||X_{t-j}|]<\infty$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi_j||X_{t-j}|<\infty$ I don't understand what is the justification for this conclusion. Intuitively I think that if the expectation of a random variable is finite, then the random variable is finite, but I need to argue in a formal way.

Using this I understand that $$\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi_jX_{t-j}|\leq \displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi_j||X_{t-j}|<\infty$$ I don't remember what is the name of the Inequality that ensures this part. With this I conclude that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\psi_jX_{t-j}$ converges absolutely that is that we need to show.